# Inverse trigonometry. Write this function in the simplest form.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

It is a question from NCERT class 12 maths textbook. From chapter 2.exercise 2.2 question no. 5(https://i.stack.imgur.com/takqu.png)

$$\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}$$

Comment: All I see is a link to a problem statement.  Can you please edit the question to include the work you've done towards the solution and where you are stuck?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1):

This inverse trigonometric function can be solved by substituting $x=\tan \theta$

Henceforth, we obtain, $$ \tan^{-1} \frac{\sec\theta -1}{\tan\theta}$$
$$=\tan^{-1} \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

At this juncture, you may apply the half angle formulae, i.e, $\sin\theta= 2\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\cos\theta=1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$,simplify thereafter to reach the final result.

**Note**: Taking the negative sign for $\sec\theta$ gives a second solution

In that case, we obtain$$ \tan^{-1} \frac{-(\sec\theta +1)}{\tan\theta}$$
$$=\tan^{-1} \frac{-(1+\cos\theta)}{\sin\theta}$$

Which can again be simplified with the half angle formulae to obtain the second solution.

Comment: How have you determined the sign of $\sec\theta$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I thought that square root here means positive square roots, which is common in the beginner type questions. I am not sure whether to include the solution considering the negative sign.

Comment: $$\sec\theta$$ may not be positive as $$\sqrt{1+x^2}$$  We can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values to make sure that

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I have added the solution considering the negative sign now. I hope there are no more details to add?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Let $$x=\tan \theta \,\, ; \,\, \theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}$$ is $1-1$ function 
$$y=\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\to \color{red} {***frac{-\pi}{2}<y<\frac{+\pi}{2}}\\ \tan(y)=tan(\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x})\\
\tan y =\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\\
\sqrt{1+x^2}=x\tan y +1\\$$to the power of two 
$$1+x^2=x^2\tan^2 y +2x\tan y +1 \\
\to x\neq 0 \\x=\dfrac{-2\tan y }{\tan^2 y -1} \to \\
f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{-2\tan x }{\tan^2 x -1}\\ \to \color{red} {***}\frac{-\pi}{2}<x<\frac{+\pi}{2}$$